Derivative of a matrix formed of partial derivatives w.r.t a vector
I need to differentiate the following expression: $\tau_s = J_A^T(\boldsymbol{q_s}) \tau_m$ w.r.t $\boldsymbol{q_s}$ , where $\boldsymbol{q_s}$ is $2\times1$ vector and $J_A^T(\boldsymbol{q_s})$ is a $2\times2$ matrix.
The derivative itself is a matrix but the first part is a 3rd rank tensor since we take the derivative of a matrix wrt to a vector: $\frac{\partial \tau_s}{\partial q_s} = (\frac{\partial J_A^T(q_s)}{\partial q_s}) \times \tau_m$
The hard part is that the only expression I have for $J_A$ is of the form:
$$J_A = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{ \frac{\partial E}{\partial \mathcal{C}_F} \frac{\partial \mathcal{C}_F}{\partial \boldsymbol{F}} \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{F}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q_s}} }{f(C_F(F(q_s))}[0] 
\\
\frac{ \frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathcal{C}_G} \frac{\partial \mathcal{C}_G}{\partial \boldsymbol{G}} \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{G}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q_s}}}{ g(C_G(G(q_s))}[0]
\end{bmatrix}$$
Where $[0]$ denotes the first line of a matrix. Each block-element of $J_A$ is then a $1\times2$ vector, where $f(C_F(F(q_s))$ and $g(C_G(G(q_s))$ are scalar valued function, and each numerator ($\frac{\partial E}{\partial \mathcal{C}_F} \frac{\partial \mathcal{C}_F}{\partial \boldsymbol{F}} \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{F}}{\partial \boldsymbol{q_s}}$ for instance) is a $3\times2$ matrix.
I tried to derive $J_A$ block by block ($3\times2$ matrix), using $\frac{u}{v}' = \frac{u'v - uv'}{v^2}$, but this leads to inconsistencies: $uv'$ is homogenous to a matrix where the full derivative should be homogenous to a 3rd rank tensor ($v^2$ is a scalar), suggesting the Leibniz rule isn't true in this case.
I also found that some people use the vec operator and the kroenecker product to flatten matrices before taking their derivative wrt a vector, but then it isn't clear how to manipulate my expression in this case.
Any idea on how to use the vec operator, or any other method to differentiate this?

$
\def\s{\star}  \def\k{\otimes}  \def\h{\odot}
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2{\grad{^2 #1}{#2^2}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\hessLR#1#2{\LR{\hess{#1}{#2}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$For ease of typing, I'll use the prime notation
$$\eqalign{
F &= F(q) &\qiq F'=\grad Fq,\q F''= \grad{F'}{q} =\hess Fq,\q etc \\
C &= C(F) &\qiq C'=\grad CF,\q C''= \grad{C'}{F} =\hess CF,\q etc \\
E &= E(C) &\qiq E'=\grad EC,\q E''= \grad{E'}{C} =\hess EC,\q etc \\
}$$
These gradients can be rearranged into the differentials
$$\eqalign{
dF &= F'\s dq \\
dC &= C'\s\c{dF} &= C'\s\c{F'\s dq} \\
dE &= E'\s\c{dC} &= E'\s\c{C'\s F'\s dq} \\
}$$
and the second order differentials
$$\eqalign{
dF' &= F''\s dq \\
dC' &= C''\s dF &= C''\s\c{F'\s dq} \\
dE' &= E''\s dC &= E''\s\c{C'\s F'\s dq} \\
}$$
where I've used $(\s)$ to indicate a generalized contraction product, which depends on the tensoral character of the quantities involved.
For example, if $\,C\;{\rm and}\;F\,$ are matrices then $C'$ is a fourth-order tensor and the $\s$ product must be a double-contraction
$$\eqalign{
dC &= C'\s dF \qiq  dC_{ij} &= \sum_k\sum_l\:C'_{ijkl}\:dF_{kl} \\
}$$
whereas, since $q$ is a vector, in the following expression the $\s$ must represent the single-contraction product
$$\eqalign{
dF &= F'\s dq \qiq  dF_{ij} &= \sum_k\:F'_{ijk}\:dq_{k} \\
}$$
You seem to be stuck on differentiating the $J$ matrix, so let's differentiate the first row
$$\eqalign{
 a^T &= e_1^TJ = e_1^T\fracLR{E'\s C'\s F'}f
\\\\
da^T
 &= e_1^T\fracLR{\c{dE'}\s C'\s F'}f
  +\; e_1^T\fracLR{E'\s\c{dC'}\s F'}f \\
  &+\; e_1^T\fracLR{E'\s C'\s\c{dF'}}f
  -\; e_1^T\lR{E'\s C'\s F'}\fracLR{\c{df}}{f^2}
\\\\
da^T
 &= e_1^T\fracLR{\CLR{E''\s C'\s F'\s dq}\s C'\s F'}f
  +\; e_1^T\fracLR{E'\s\CLR{C''\s F'\s dq}\s F'}f \\
 &+\; e_1^T\fracLR{E'\s C'\s\CLR{F''\s dq}}f
  -\; e_1^T\lR{E'\s C'\s F'}\fracLR{\c{f'\s C'\s F'\s dq}}{f^2}
}$$
where $e_1$ denotes the first Cartesian basis vector.
The remaining task is to rearrange this into a form
from which you can recover the desired gradient, i.e.
$$ da = M\s dq \qiq \grad{a}{q} = M $$
There are various techniques to accomplish this including vectorization, or the use of tensor/index notation.
IMHO, the simplest technique is to recall that the component-wise self-gradient of a vector is equal to the corresponding Cartesian basis vector, i.e.
$$\grad q{q_k} = e_k$$
Applying this to the previous result yields the component-wise gradient of the first row
$$\eqalign{
\grad{a^T}{q_k}
 &= e_1^T\fracLR{\LR{E''\s C'\s F'\s\c{e_k}}\s C'\s F'}f
  +\; e_1^T\fracLR{E'\s\LR{C''\s F'\s\c{e_k}}\s F'}f \\
 &+\; e_1^T\fracLR{E'\s C'\s\LR{F''\s\c{e_k}}}f
  -\; e_1^T\lR{E'\s C'\s F'}\fracLR{{f'\s C'\s F'\s\c{e_k}}}{f^2}
\\\\
}$$
The second row can be handled in a similar fashion, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
 b^T &= e_1^T\fracLR{H'\s C'\s G'}g \qq\qq\qq
}$$
